# Cannot subscribe RSS with IE9 and SharePoint 2013

Tags: internet-explorer, rss

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. We use HTTPS as default protocol for SharePoint browsing.

When our users browse with IE9, open a library, click RSS, the page `/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx` will be displayed.

When user click on "Subscribe to this RSS feed" link it jumps to `feeds://xxxxxx`. Notice that the protocal become `feeds` instead of `feed` which IE9 do not recognize ass an RSS format.

Also, even I manually change the `feeds` to `feed` I still cannot subscribe it because the "RSS" orange button on IE9 is grey out.

What can I do to manually subscribe to SharePoint 2013 using IE9?